# Checking if List<Tuple<T, T>> is empty

Tags: c#, collections, tuples, .net-4.5

I want to check if `List<Tuple<T, T>>` is empty. Using  [these](http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/check-if-ienumerable-or-list-type-is-empty-null/) techniques for checking if `List<string>` is empty, I have noticed that one of the check is not working in my case:

```
List<Tuple<byte, string>> intermediateResult = new List<Tuple<byte, string>>();

//not working
if(intermediateResult!= null)
    Console.WriteLine("not empty");
else
    Console.WriteLine("empty");

//working
if(intermediateResult.Any())
Console.WriteLine("not empty");
else
Console.WriteLine("empty");
```

Could anyone tell what the first check is not working?

Comment: What are you expecting? `intermediateResult` is never going to be null because you've just assigned a new instance.

Comment: ? It isn't null since you've just new'ed it?

Comment: Yeah, I just have tested the example from the website and it is not working there, too.

Comment: Empty and null are two entirely different things IMO. If the list were *null*, it couldn't be empty, because it isn't there. So your second check would throw a NullReferenceException. You are initializing an *empty* list, so of course your first check "fails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explanation of not working part :-

it not working because you are intializtion your collection like this

```
List<Tuple<byte, string>> intermediateResult = new List<Tuple<byte, string>>();
```

when you intialize like this than intermediateResult is not null. which is true.

Answer (score 1):

With that line you are checking if the list has been allocated or not. So you are checking the right behaviour of the new command.
An empty list would still have an address in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
List<Tuple<byte, string>> intermediateResult = new List<Tuple<byte, string>>();
```

creates new instance of `List<Tuple<byte, string>>` and assigns it to `intermediateResult` - so obviously `intermediateResult` is not null after executing this line.